# Having problem understanding the complex fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

Here is my textbook, and I am wondering where that conjugate of $g(x)$ comes from? Why it isn't the integral of $f(x)g(x)$?[image]

It seems to contradict this theorem, I am not quite sure[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why *would* it be the integral of $f(x)g(x)$? The equation $$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-L}^Lf(x)\bar g(x)dx$$ is a *definition* of the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space). The reason is because one of the inner product axioms requires that $\langle f,g\rangle=\overline{\langle g,f\rangle}$ (what Wikipedia calls *conjugate symmetry*), which is not satisfied if we define the inner product to be the integral of $f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you first. my question comes from another piece of theorem in this textbook, and I have edited my quesiton

Comment: @Cooper I believe in that other context $f,g$ are real-valued functions, so since the conjugate of a real valued function is itself it is not necessary to write the conjugate symbol.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks